# arrays in android programming

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am new in android programming. 
Here is my question

I tried to declare an array before onCreate() method like

```
int[] userselected;
```

Note that i want to use this array to store ids of buttons user had pressed.
Then i tried to find no. of elements in this array with

```
int noOfElements = userselected.length;
```

which game me an error.
Then I changed declaration to

```
int[] userselected = {};
```

it worked, but when i tried to put an id in this array with code

```
userselected[1] = R.id.textview1;
```

it again gave me an error.
I also tried declaring array as

```
int[] userselected = new int[4];
```

but then, when i tried to find how many elements have already been stored,
     userselected.length

always gave number 4.

Please tell me, how can i get what i want

Comment: use `List` then. It is dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html). It will give you a more flexible structure giving your case.

```
ArrayList<Integer> userselected  = new  ArrayList<Integer>();
userselected.add(R.id.textview1); //To add id.
int noOfElement = userselected.size(); //to get size
```

Comment: What is problem in this code example? I am asking to downvoters...... first read the rule to do downvote and then proceed. Don't show here your jealous behavior.

Comment: is user asking for ArrayList any where? The OP can suggest that you can use ArrayList giving reason why to use it.

Comment: Thats a good reason to downvote, but when you give downvote you should be clear about your thought to OP. Am I right?

Comment: @LalitPoptani Sorry. Updated with reason. With his requirement, arrays will be difficult to implement. ArrayList is what he should use giving his specific case.

Comment: Yes, sometimes answerer after getting down-vote are able to rectify their mistake in answer. So, its not mandatory to everytime give reason. But as you asked I gave you the reason for down-voting but the OP still hasn't

Comment: yes buddy !! your solution worked. I dont know, why you were downvoted. but all i required was a solution, and you gave that

Answer (score 1):

an array is **fixed size**. so when you declare this array

`int[] userselected = new int[4]`

you are creating an array with a fixed size of 4. The array index is zero based so its from [0] to [3]. I recommend you use an ArrayList object like the top answer states

when you do this:

`int[] userselected = {};`

it is the same as this:

`int[] userselected = new int[0]; // empty`

and you got an error from this:

`int[] userselected;`

because you have not allocated any space in memory

Answer (score 0):

Java primitive arrays, such as `int[]`, are constant in length and cannot contain more than their initial length. If you need an array that can change in size, you need to use fx. a `List` implementation. I would suggest you read up on basic Java before you start developing Android, it would save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: You are right, but learning this way isn't bad either, i think

Answer (score 0):

I think this page can help: http://www.javaclass.info/classes/java-array/array-examples-demonstration-and-code-snippets.php

In the array declaration you do, you say that its size is 4 elements, therefore the length method will always return 4.

regards

Answer (score 0):

declare it as a integer array then Add this to your code

```
Integer a=0;
for (int i=0;i>userselected.length;i++)
{
   if(userselected[i]!=null)
    {
      a++;
    }
}
```

then `a` will give you the count you need:) cheers:)

Comment: its giving operator != is not defined for the type int, null.
Also your loop is incorrect, which i corrected